# Append at end of line in CSV file - Java

Tags: java, file, csv

I want to add an ID at the end of a line in a a CSV file using Java if there's a match.

This is how my code looks:

```
        String tempFile = "/C:/Users/chid.kulkarni/Desktop/JSON_CSV/temp.csv";
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String url1 = "";
        String Desc = "";

        try
        {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            url1 = x.next();
            Desc= x.next();

            if(url1.equals(editTerm))
            {
                System.out.println("Found!!, URL:"+url1);
                System.out.println("Edit_term:"+editTerm);
            }
        }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Input

editTerm : www.airbnb.com

CSV file

```
URL                 Desc            
www.google.com     searches web
www.airbnb.com     House rentals
www.gmail.com      email application
```

Desired Output: if URL (www.airbnb.com) == editTerm (www.airbnb.com)

```
URL                 Desc               ID
www.google.com     searches web
www.airbnb.com     House rentals       100001
www.gmail.com      email application
```

How do I achieve this?

I have seen blogs/tuts about adding an entire column. In my case, I just want to add an id to a specific line, instead of appending an entire column.

Comment: In effect, what you are doing *is* adding a column, just with a blank / null value on certain records

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code within try-catch block and achieved desired output. This version specifically writes Id value of "100001" for editTerm. You can later add a function to retrieve targetId specific for an editTerm.

I had to get rid of the last character of "Desc", which was causing a newline.

```
    String targetId = "100001";
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
        x.hasNext();
        url1 = x.next();
        Desc= x.next();
        Desc = Desc.substring(0,Desc.length()-1);
        pw.write(url1+","+Desc+",ID\n");
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            url1 = x.next();
            Desc= x.next();
            Desc = Desc.substring(0,Desc.length()-1);
            pw.write(url1+","+Desc);
            if(url1.equals(editTerm))
            {
                System.out.println("Found!!, URL:"+url1);
                System.out.println("Edit_term:"+editTerm);
                //targetId = findTargetId(editTerm);// id finder function 
                pw.write(","+targetId);
            }
            pw.write("\n");
        }
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```